# Wrong scrolling of floating action button

Tags: android, android-scrollview, floating-action-button

I have two FABs (FAB: floating action button) on the top of an `ImageView` and one on the right bottom of another `ImageView`

My problem is that I'm trying to make the top FAB to be fixed and the other one scrollable. However, I'm getting results contrary to what I wanted. I tried taking one FAB out of `ScrollView` but it still doesn't work as both the FABs will initially be over the `ImageView`.

My layout:

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/detail_page_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/White"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="60dp">
            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="top"/>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </FrameLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/viewB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/detail_page_text1"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
            <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/detail_page_text2"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
            <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/detail_page_text3"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_local_phone_black_24dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/mobile_number"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/rating"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:paddingLeft="120dp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/detail_pager_button"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:text="Entry Via GuestList"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textSize="17sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="@string/dummy_text"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="8"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/event_list_text"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/more_button"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llDateContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:showDividers="middle">

                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:scrollbars="none">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llTimeContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:showDividers="middle">

                </LinearLayout>


            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="8"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/choose_table_text"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/more_button"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/event_list_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="8"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/persons_list_text"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/more_button"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/person_list_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/venue_detail"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/clock_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/clock_1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                />
                <com.ct.listrtrial.Custom.CustomTextViewMedium
                    android:id="@+id/opening_hours_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/opening_hours_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingStart="15dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/detail_page_viewpager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make Your Layout Similar To Following

```
<FrameLayout>


    <ScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView>

            <fab1>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <fab2>

</FrameLayout>
```

Make A FrameLayout As Root , Place the Fab1 will be on top of ImageView and Fab2 Top oF ScrollView

So the Fab1 Will be Fixed On Imageview and Scrollable And The Fab2 Will not be Scrollable

Hope it Helps

Comment: hi @GuruCharan when i set image to fab it doesnt take the full height and width of fab

Comment: Consider Using `app:fabSize="normal"` **or** `app:fabSize="mini"` to adjust FAB Size, Use `android:scaleType="center"` in your ImageButton to avoid auto resize.

Comment: but how can i add an image to fab which completely covers fab

Comment: Be Little Specific , I dont understand what you are asking
If you want to change Complete Fab Button Style,Use A custom Drawable to Make your Fab However you want.

Comment: I'm trying to add an image to fab but te problem is image is showing very small

Comment: Use `android:scaleType` to adjust image size in FAB

Comment: IF you want to use ImageButton As FAB Use
`<ImageButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
   style="@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton"/>`